# different apache redirect/rewrite rules for one domain

Tags: apache, redirect, url-rewriting, virtualhost

Can someone help me with url redirect/rewrite?

1. example.com/url/* --> newdomain.com/new/path/url/* *not showing the forwarded url*
2. example.com/* --> newdomain.com/new/path/to/go/*  *not showing the forwarded url*
3. example.com --> newdomain.com  *showing forwarded url*

I've tried RedirectMatch or Rewirite Rules in the VHost file...

1. RedirectMatch ^/url/(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/new/path/url/url/$1
2. RedirectMatch ^/(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/new/path/go/$1
3. RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1

Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To surpress the forwarded URL use [P] as Parameter and use rewrites instead of redirects, for the startpage use R=301 to permanentely rewrite to new domain:

if really needed (in case of both domains hosted on one server without vhost) put this in front:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$
RewriteRule .? - [S=3]
RewriteRule  ^/$ http://newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule  ^/url/(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/new/path/url/$1 [P,L]
RewriteRule  ^/(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/new/path/to/go/$1 [P,L]
```

Let us know if it works as intended and if not, what went wrong :)

---

**UPDATE**

Put this in LoadModule conf:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

And this where your rewrite etc. are:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com$
RewriteRule  ^/$ http://newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]

ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPassMatch  /url/(.+) http://newdomain.com/new/path/url/$1
ProxyPassMatch  /(.+) http://newdomain.com/new/path/to/go/$1
ProxyPassReverse / http://newdomain.com/
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I've put all three rewrite rules in the vhost and rule#1 is rewriting correct. rule#2 and rule#3 only redirects. In this cases it should rewrite the redirecting url (newdomain.com/new/path/url) to "example.com/url" or for rule#3 example.com/test. Do you have any idea how this could work? :-)

Comment: I thought you wanted to hide these two rewrites and so I used [P] instead of [R]. But I am not 100% sure that I got your last comment... Can you tell me what you type in, what you get in the browser and what it is that you expect? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: sorry for the confusion... ;-) at the moment I type **example.com/url/test** and get **newdomain.com/new/path/url/test** but I want to see **example.com/url/test** (it still  has to redirect to newdomain.com/new/path/url)  - this is for rewriterule #2 in your answer. same way for rewrite rule #3 except the /url. Thanks!! :-)

Comment: thanks, but still no success... it keeps showing me **newdomain.com/new/path/url** or **newdomain.com/new/path/to/go** :-(

Comment: That's kinda confusing^^ Are there any other rewrites beside those I listed? And you don't call www.example? Won't work with www...or didn't so far, just edited it to work with www.example.com. Do you know the ProxyPass(Match) Snytax? Maybe that would work...but it requires additional modules, see edited post

Comment: yes, it's very confusing... i've tried with proxypass, but now i get **example.com/new/path/url** - at least it is closer to **example.com/url** ;-) no, in this vhost are no other rules, but maybe it is important to mention, that /new/path/url are no physical paths(they point to a api running on the server). another important issue is, that i use cloudflare dns and automatic ssl encryption. when i activate cloudflare http proxy, i get a dns 1000 error "points to prohibited ip"(with rewrite and proxypass rules)...i have no clue what's going wrong...

Comment: I have no idea how cloudflare dns comes into play here, but maybe example.com is an alias of cloudflare.com and newdomain.com isn't and the proxy to another name is prohibited by cloudflare? dunno about dns error 1000. Maybe you can change the dns-entries so that exmple.com becomes an alias for newdomain.com? As far as the rewrites go, I am pretty sure even my first solution should have done the job^^

Comment: hi! first i want to apologize for my late answer...indeed, it was a cloudflare proxy issue, so you only can use dns(no proxy)-with proxy enabled you can easily set up a https redirection... ;-) so with proxy turned off your rewrite works perfect-THANK YOU!!! :-) but do you know how it is possible for your rewrite-rules to make them https :// example.com/ and https :// example.com/url ? ssl is set up and works, i only can't figure out how to rewrite rule... :-/

Comment: Hey, glad to hear that :) Add the 's' in the rewrite-target like: `RewriteRule  ^/$ https://newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]` and `RewriteRule  ^/url/(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/new/path/url/$1 [P,L]`  etc. ...

Comment: Hey! :-)
Rewrite-rule #1 works fine, but the second and third do not rewrite to https:// example.com or https:// example.com/url/test...i am still testing, but no success... ;-)